# Redirect domain.com to www.domain.com but can countine go to domain.com/sitemap.xml

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to Redirect domain.com to www.domain.com using .htaccess but can countine go to domain.com/sitemap.xml
Because I use blogger to make my blog. but when I added an domain for it, it's not move the sitemap.xml file
It's still tienganhratde.blogspot.com/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(?!sitemap\.xml) http://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: It don't work at all. tienganhratde.com/sitemap.xml
And it's also effect my subdomain social.tienganhratde.com is redirected to www.social.tienganhratde.com